# Is there a way to return different key names for toJson and fromJson methods, json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

Is it possible to use json_serializable and have different key names for same field for toJson and fromJson.

ex json-data:

```
{
"idUser": 123,
/// some other fields
}
```

incoming json_data from another APIs

```
{
"id" : 123,
/// some other fields
}
```

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Id extends INetworkModel<Id> {
  Id(this.idUser);

  final int? idUser;

  @override
  Id fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$IdFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() => _$IdToJson(this);
}
```

for that particular id field, I want to map it as idUser for toJson and id as fromJson.

based on what I saw for json_serializable docs it's possible to manipulate field values with custom toJson and fromJson methods but didn't see any other option to manipulate key names in JSON based on the method.

I would be very glad if someone enlightens me thanks ahead!

Comment: Sorry for the deleted answer. I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to having 2 sources for the same property:

Parse both as nullable, and have a getter to retrieve the value. Something like:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Id extends INetworkModel<Id> {
  Id(this.idUser, this.id);

  final int? idUser;
  final int? id;
  int? get theUserId => id ?? isUser;


  @override
  Id fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$IdFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() => _$IdToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: This seems more feasible than other approaches

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, however you can do

Go to `yourfile.g.dart`

```
part of 'yourfile.dart';
```

> as you stated that **I want to map it as idUser for toJson and id as fromJson.**

```
Id _$IdFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Id(
      idUser: json['id'] as int,
     // your rest of fields
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$IdToJson(Id instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': idUser,
      // your rest of fields
    };
```